# org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <ILLEGAL_CHARACTER> JSF+Richfaces Error

Tags: java, spring, jsf, richfaces

below shows my code in JSF+Spring project.please help me to sort out this issue

thanks

here is my jsf code in xhtml file

i tried with @form / @this also. but same result

error is my inputtext not submitted to controller

```
<a4j:region id="panel-region">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="SAM Selector"/>
    </f:facet>
    <rich:panel style="clear:both;" header="Search SAM" styleClass="col" id="panelSamSearch">

        <ui:decorate template="/jsf/templates/two_columns.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="left_label">*Search By</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="left_field">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{pOSController.samType}" id="samType">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="a" itemLabel=""/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="samUid" itemLabel="SAM UID"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="samDid" itemLabel="SAM DID"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="status" itemLabel="Status"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="right_label">
                <h:inputText value="#{pOSController.samValue}" id="samValue"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="right_field">
                <a4j:commandButton id="samBtnSearch" value="Search" execute="lp"
                                   action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging(rich:element('samType').value,rich:element('samValue').value)}"
                                   render="#{rich:clientId('dataTableSamView')}"/>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:decorate>

    </rich:panel>
```

here shows my error

```
May 05, 2014 1:13:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/cms-web] threw exception [/jsf/popups/samPosTagginPopup.xhtml @29,230 action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging({rich:element('samType')}.value,{rich:element('samValue')}.value)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging({rich:element('samType')}.value,{rich:element('samValue')}.value)}]] with root cause
org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <ILLEGAL_CHARACTER> "{ "" at line 1, column 35.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    ")" ...
    "!" ...
    "not" ...
    "empty" ...
    "-" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...

    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:2217)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:2099)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.MethodParameters(ELParser.java:1153)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.ValueSuffix(ELParser.java:1047)
    at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Value(ELParser.java:980)
```

**EDITED**

i added

```
<a4j:commandButton id="samBtnSearch" value="Search" execute="lp" action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging(rich:component('samType'),rich:component('samValue'))}" render="#{rich:clientId('dataTableSamView')}"  />
```

then string come as like below.its not pass value of field.just name which i passes returns :-)
`document.getElementById('frmMasPosTagging:dataTablePosView:0:samType')`

Comment: `action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging(rich:element('samType').value,rich:element('samValue').value)}` from the fist listing differs from `action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging({rich:element('samType')}.value,{rich:element('samValue')}.value)}"` contained in the exception message. Are you sure the runtime uses the file displayed in the first listing?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin : Dear friend, I edited code .pleaes tell me the way to return value from inputtext field

Answer (score 0):

change the line:

```
action="{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging(rich:element('samType').value,rich:element('samValue').value)}"
```

to `action="{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging()}`
the value 'samType' and 'samValue'can be accessed in the controller as these are mapped to a backing bean, and backing bean would be updated.so no need to send the values from UI
i assume pOSController have getters and setters for 'samType' and 'samValue'